# Kotlin syntax: how to define resource in a loop

Tags: arrays, kotlin, syntax

I've a series of bitmaps that I want to set in an array of bitmaps.

```
var wallFaces: Array<Bitmap>? = null
```

I can do this: (it works)

```
init {
    wallFaces?.set(0,BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.resources, R.drawable.brick_wall_face_0))
    wallFaces?.set(1,BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.resources, R.drawable.brick_wall_face_1))
    etc...
}
```

But for more flexibility, I'd like to do something like this:

```
init {
    for(i in 0..1) {
        wallFaces?.set(i,BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.resources, R.drawable.brick_wall_face_<i>))
    }
}
```

I can't find the right syntax so that it complies. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
for(i in 0..1) {
    val idString = "brick_wall_face_$i"
    val drawableId = context.resources.getIdentifier(idString, "drawable", context.packageName)
    wallFaces?.set(i, BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.resources, drawableId))
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It works perfect! Now, I'm stuck because I can't manage to use the variable. I get a "kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException" when I do this: wallFace = wallFaces!!.get(id). Do you know why?

Comment: @LuTo i think because `wallFaces` is `null` and therefore `!!` throws  `KotlinNullPointerException`, [The !! Operator](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#the--operator)